# find a select option with same value as select data-status and load option as "selected" with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am loading 2 separate ajax responses into a select dropdown and the select dropdown will have a data-status, what I am looking to achieve is to loop through the options and find the option that has the same value as the select data-status and load it as "selected".

Given my html code generated from my ajax call:

```
<select class="orderCurrentStatus" data-status="1215458">
  <option value="608653">Goods Received</option>
  <option value="608654">Purchase - Awaiting Payment</option>
  <option value="608655">Purchase - Payment Received</option>
  <option value="766705">EXCHANGE FEE PAID</option>
  <option value="838627">Order Refunded</option>
  <option value="1215458">Goods Dispatched</option>
  <option value="2322397">Paid - Custom Order Under Production</option>
  <option value="2384172">WRONG/INCOMPLETE ADDRESS!</option>
  <option value="2544576">Paid - Awaiting Pre-Ordered Items</option>
</select>
```

My attempt to make it work:

```
var order_status = $(".orderCurrentStatus").data("status");
var options = $(".orderCurrentStatus option");

if (options.val(order_status)) {
  $(this).attr("selected");
}
```

I just can't get it to work.

Comment: $(this).attr('selected','');

Comment: You can't just set an attribute to "selected" and not set a value. Just tried it out on my website, and it doesn't work. You have to set a value, even if it's absolutely nothing (example in above comment from me). By default, if you don't put anything in the second pair of single quotes, it sets it to selected (which is what I'm guessing you'll want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the attribute selector `[value="'+ order_status +'"]` in order to select an `option` element that has a value equal to the variable `order_status`.

From there, set the `selected` property value to `true` or `selected`.

```
$('.orderCurrentStatus option[value="'+ order_status +'"]').prop('selected', true);
```

There were a couple issues with your initial code.

- The variable `this` refers to the global object, in this case the `window` object, since there is no functional scope.
- If you don't specify a value when using the `.attr()` method, the `selected` attribute value is returned. You need to specify a second parameter in order to set a value for the `selected` attribute. Specifying `true` or `selected` will work in your case. However, the `.prop()` method is better suited for this since you should be setting the property.

---

Additionally, if you want to do this for all `select` elements, then you could iterate over them, then retreive the `data-status` attribute value, and set the corresponding `option` element's `selected` property:

```
$('select').each(function () {
  var status = $(this).data("status");
  $(this).find('option[value="'+ status +'"]').prop('selected', true);
});
```

Comment: That, or you know, you could just say 'selected'.

Comment: Thanks for the work around it really worked well just took long to realize that I had to get this call after the Ajax request that populates the options inside the select dropdown Thanks Lol

Answer (score 0):

You should somehow check if an option with the value specified exists! This what you actually tried is assigning a value to every option element.

This should be simple solution:

```
var order_status = $(".orderCurrentStatus").data("status");

if( $('.orderCurrentStatus option[value=' + order_status + ']').length )
    $('.orderCurrentStatus option[value=' + order_status + ']').attr('selected','selected');
```

You could verify the code on JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/cwma9h5m/

Answer (score 0):

You can always iterate through the option values to match with the data-status value.

```
var status = $('.orderCurrentStatus').data("status");
 $('.orderCurrentStatus option').each(function(){
    if( $(this).val()==status){
     $(this).prop('selected', true);
    }
 });
```